# prove that an interval of the form $(a,b]$ can be covered by open intervals of the form $(a_k,b_k)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to prove that an interval of the form $(a,b]$ can be covered by open intervals of the form $(a_k,b_k)$. I tried to prove it using union of intervals of the form $(a_k,b_k + \frac{\epsilon}{2^k})$, but I am not sure if the intervals should be like that or maybe $(a_k - \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}, b_k)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "covered"? Will the single interval $(a,b+1)$ do?

Comment: @MishaLavrov covered is like

$(a,b] \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_k,b_k + \frac{\epsilon}{2^k})$

Comment: Well, $(a,b] \subseteq (a,b+1)$, so that still seems like it does the trick.

Comment: Do you need inclusion? Or equality? The first one is trivial as @MishaLavrov pointed out, while the second is impossible (since an union of open set is open and $(a,b]$ is not open)

Comment: @Taladris I need inclusion, not  equality

Comment: Your example $\bigcup (a_k,b_k+\epsilon/2^k)$ is weird, because if you let $c_k=b_k+\epsilon/2^k,$ that becomes a simpler example $\bigcup (a_k,c_k).$ Why not just use that as the example?

Comment: The question is unclear, as @MishaLavrov has pointed out.

Comment: If Misha Lavrov's suggestion works, you should indicate it. If Misha's example does not work, you should tell us whatever additional requirements you have (unmentioned in your post) that would disallow it.